# Enable Hide Ribbon link in settings gear box

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

[image: SharePoint Hide Ribbon in Setting Gear box]

I am new to branding the SharePoint 2013. I am trying something from designer, but suddenly the "Hide Ribbon" link is disabled and not working. Please help me on this.

How do you enable this "Hide Ribbon" link?

Comment: Your page is Checkin and Publish?